# time wont show time in textfield with datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have this field where I can insert the date and time through a datetimepicker:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
     });
</script>
```

When I select the date and time, it will show the date and time perfectly in the textfield. Also when I press the submit button it will store the date and time perfectly through a `DateTime()` type in the database. Now I format the date that I read from the database from y-m-d to d-m-y in a function which is working fine. The problem is, if I go back to the page I submitted the date time in, it shows all the information I submitted in the input fields, except for the time. It only shows the date.

This is my input field:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value={{$date}} id='datepicker'>
```

When I `var_dump($date);` a few lines before the input field, I get the date and time perfectly like I want it:

11-04-2015 09:09

but in the textfield it shows:

11-04-2015

So there is nothing wrong with the variable `$date`.

When I submit again, it will save 11-04-2014 00:00:00.

Which makes me think there's something wrong with the format the default value is displayed in the textfield.

I already tried:

```
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy HH::mm'
```

in the script.

I use:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

and:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

**EDIT:**

Timepicker format JS:

```
timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
```

Comment: Did you tried this format `dateFormat: dd-mm-yy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: pls show how you are saving date in variable `$date`

Comment: as mentioned by **`user3454479`** you should change dateformat to `dateFormat: 'yyy-dd-mm HH:mm:ss'`. It is displaying in `dd-mm-yy` format because of your datepicker's dateformat.

Comment: @krishna I already tried: 'dd-mm-yy HH::mm' as I mentioned in my question. That should work as well right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typographical error in this line:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value={{$date}} id='datepicker'>
```

**The date needs to go between quotes as the rest of the attributes**. Otherwise it will stop at the first space break.

Right now, using the date that you specified, the generated code will look like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="date" value=11-04-2015 09:09 id='datepicker'>
```

You can even see how StackOverflow highlights the "09:09" in a different color. And if you run the code snippet, you'll see that only the date is displayed.

Now, if you wrap the value between quotes, the result will be:

```html
<input type="text" name="date" value="11-04-2015 09:09" id='datepicker'>
```

And the text field will display both date and time, so the datepicker will also process the time instead of ignoring it.

Comment: You legend! This worked. I thought it was definitly something with the timepicker I added.